# How to fork Ethereum from the current state?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, nodes, hardforks, forks

I've read a lot of tutorials and guides that teach how to set up your own private network from scratch.

However, how would I do that from the current state of the blockchain? Instead of generating a new genesis, I'd like to simply "fork" to a private network in-house.

Related but incomplete: [How to fork my own version of ETH?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2014/how-to-fork-my-own-version-of-eth)[related](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2014/how-to-fork-my-own-version-of-eth)

*irrelevant, but: this is strictly educational*

Answer (score 2):

You can use [testrpc](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli) (now renamed as ganache-cli) to fork from another instance.

> -f or --fork: Fork from another currently running Ethereum client at a given block. Input should be the HTTP location and port of the other client, e.g. `http://localhost:8545`. You can optionally specify the block to fork from using an @ sign: `http://localhost:8545@1599200`.