# Is it possible to interact with smart contracts on mainnet but from a testnet?

Tags: contract-development, web3js, testnets

I am writing a script in web3js to interact with a smart contract that is on the mainnet. This is not a smart contract I control.

I want to test / develop using a testnet. So how can I check my script runs correctly without directly interacting with it on mainnet? Or do I have to rely on that smart contract being deployed on one of the testnets?

Comment: You can use ganache-cli/testrpc to fork mainnet to a private testnet https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/how-to-fork-ethereum-from-the-current-state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to rely on it being deployed on the testnet you're using. You can deploy the contract yourself if you want to be sure it's there.

Comment: Is there a way to search contracts on the test net? And have had a try at creating my own from the source of the contract on eitherscan. Is it just as simple as taking the bytecode and interface json? As i keep getting failed txns