# Want to run a local fork of Ropsten

Tags: parity, ropsten, forks, ganache

I would like to run a local fork of Ropsten to interact with some of the smart contracts without having to fill up from the tap.

My plan was to start a light parity node as follows:

```
parity --chain ropsten --light --no-serve-light
```

This worked well, however, when I try to run a local `ganache-cli` fork:

```
ganache-cli --fork <here I copy-pasted my enode:// URL>
```

It crashes with the following error:

```
Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node <my enode://>
```

Comment: A duplicate of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/how-to-fork-ethereum-from-the-current-state/

Comment: Hi Ismael, thanks for flagging this! I think this is a broader precise question on how to fork Ropsten via a light Parity node rather than how —fork works in ganache-cli which I have already described as prior knowledge in the formulation of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parity should be run in RPC mode as follows:

```
parity --chain ropsten --light --no-serve-light --jsonrpc-port=8545
```

And then the following command works to issue a fork:

```
ganache-cli --fork http://localhost:8545
```

Answer (score 2):

Ganache expect a JSON-RPC node. Something like this should work

```
ganache-cli --fork http://localhost:8545
```

Comment: Thanks Ismael, I can broadcast an RPC server from another ganache instance, but do you know if Parity nodes are able to broadcast an RPC server?

Comment: My goal is to run a local fork of Ropsten where I'm able to transact with existing balances without affecting the testnet itself.

Comment: Sorry, but I've not used parity for RPC, but I know that it has a geth compatible mode. Probably you should search for questions about how to enable RPC in parity.

Answer (score -2):

For ropsten, you can easily mine ether, if you use a GPU. The difficulty is very low and you can mine 50-90% of the blocks. I used this approach multiple times and was able to mine 10-20k ether in a day multiple times.