# Truffle testing a contract against an already-deployed external contract

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

Let's say I'm writing an escrow contract. The conditions of this escrow are based on the properties of a second already-deployed contract on Kovan and mainnet. Should I skip testing my escrow contract on Ganache and deploy to Kovan every time I need to test to access the other contract? Or should I somehow find a way to replicate the conditional logic into a contract that I can deploy to Ganache and test against that?

It would be great if I could clone a deployed contract with its current state to my Ganache chain. Is there anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `ganache-cli` supports forking public chains. I have never tried this, by it should be possible, see also [Want to run a local fork of Ropsten](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45709/want-to-run-a-local-fork-of-ropsten).

Copying only the contract state is also possible in theory. You could try follow the instructions here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/40280/33305. Forking would be a less error-prone method though I guess.