# Is it possible to run multiple Ganache nodes for private test network?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, testnets, ganache

I wonder if i can create my own private cluster as it can be  done with Geth for development & test purposes :
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Setting-up-private-network-or-local-cluster#local-cluster

I gave shot by running multiple Ganache on same PC. But obviously failed to run as it tried to access port that is already taken by previous one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run multiple instances of ganache locally. You'll need to specify a dedicated port for each one, see `-p` parameter (https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli).

However, you'll not be able to connect these instances to form a local cluster. Each process will run independently an own chain. It's not what it was designed for.

Comment: Thanks. I will continue my distributed app development on undistributed Ganache.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to connect them, when the same genesis.json was used?

Comment: @pubkey genesis.json is not for connection but it is more about running on same chain. If Ganache doesnt provide any p2p node networking capability; nodes can not listen eachother and synch for the latest mined blocks.

Answer (score 0):

you can run multiple instance using different ports.
`ganache-cli -p 8546`  and also you can fork currently running client to another client.
`ganace-cli -p 8545 -f http://localhost:8546`

more:[How to fork Ethereum from the current state?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/how-to-fork-ethereum-from-the-current-state)