# Connecting to a blockchain started with ganache-cli with Ganache GUI

Tags: ganache, ganache-cli

I start a blockchain with ganache-cli, then I create a workspace in Ganache GUI the same seed phrase and port, but I keep getting this error in Ganache:

I get and error

> this port is being used by another application

Is it possible to connect with the GUI to a running blockchain, if so how do I do this?

Comment: Either you have another Ganache process already listening on the same port, or you possibly have Parity or Geth listening on the same port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because both the applications cannot use the same port. You have to kill the cli process to use the Ganache GUI in the same port. But this would mean you will loose the data in the cli node.

Using the same seed phrase just means that you are unlocking the same 10 accounts in both the cases. The blockchains are different. you can think of this as using same accounts in two different testnet.

<s>You can try using a different port in Ganache GUI but using the same network ID as that was used to start the ganache-cli node. This might work but I am unable to test it right now.</s>

Edit: Connecting multiple ganache instances will not work. Ganache is not designed for this. ref: [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/51575/53608)