# Set block size and block number

Tags: remix

Is there a way to set the block size and the block number in Remix IDE?
If not, could you suggest another platform where I can change these parameters?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change parameters of the eth network, you can run ganache locally on your computer. This is an Ethereum simulator where you can change the parameters of the network. For example - this starts a simulate network with a higher gas limit (aka setting the blocksize larger)

`ganache-cli -l 0xFFFFFFFF`

Note when you run this command an output will be `Listening on 127.0.0.1:8545` -- this will be important in the next step.

After having run this command you can connect to this local ganache instance through remix by changing the `Environment` variable in the `Deploy & Run Transactions` page. In this drop down, select `web3 provider` and then use default suggest end point `http://127.0.0.1:8545` (we saw this earlier). Now any transactions you submit through remix will be sent to your ganche-cli network which you have the power to easily change the parameters of - like gas limit.

For increasing the block number - there are a few options - by default, ganache mines a block every time a signed transaction is submitted. You can just submit a ton of transactions to increase the block number. You can also try changing the `--blockTime` flag in ganache-cli so that blocks will be mined over time (I've had trouble with this in ganache-cli, but it's worked with ganache-ui)

Depending on what you are trying to do - [openzeppelin-test-helper - advanceBlock](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-test-helpers/blob/64fc8732a1e3a0b9230246a8a4a2fd0a282fa22e/docs/modules/ROOT/pages/api.adoc#advanceblock) function may also be an alternative helpful way to address this

> advanceBlock async function time.advanceBlock() Forces a block to be
> mined, incrementing the block height.

Comment: would I be able to increase the number of blocks, as well?

Comment: I've updated the answer with some potential solutions for increasing the block number

Comment: hi again, can I have more than one node with ganache?

Comment: not really - you can run multiple instances of ganache on different ports - but the wont interact with each other like nodes https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/51572/is-it-possible-to-run-multiple-ganache-nodes-for-private-test-network

Comment: how cloud I mimic a distributed network then? wouldn't this work [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/how-to-fork-ethereum-from-the-current-state) I need to simulate one client and one enterprise for instance how would I do that?

Comment: I don't think forking is what you're looking for. Once you fork, the ganache instances are running a different network. If you need to test on a multinode eth network - you can run multiple eth nodes on your local computer to simulate a private network. There are also some nice setups with docker that create a dockerized private network on your local. I've not used this specific example - but this should give you the general idea of how this would work. https://github.com/alchemist107/Poa-Blockchain-Docker-Compose-env/blob/master/docker-compose.yml