# Can ganache-cli connects to another ganache-cli?

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, private-blockchain, ganache

Is it possible to create a private network using ganache-cli?
Can a ganache-cli running on port 8545 connect to ganache-cli running on port 9545?

Can we use ganache-cli as a node? Or it is a complete network?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. It's not the purpose ganache-cli was designed for.

However, you could fork from an existing network with the -f parameter. See [How to fork Ethereum from the current state?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/how-to-fork-ethereum-from-the-current-state)