# How can I create a new public blockchain cloned from Ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, blockchain-fork

Basically I know how to create a private blockchain, or Testnet,

But how would you go about creating a complete fork of Ethereum, while changing the name of Ethereum to something custom ?

For example I know Musicoin did fork Ethereum and create their own blockchain, they even renamed geth command line to something else, so this is definitely possible.

What should I do, where to look at to start this process ? (After forking ethereum codebase)

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2014/how-to-fork-my-own-version-of-eth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already know how to create a private Ethereum chain, then you're already most of the way there. The difference between "public" and "private" is basically the process of publicising and allowing others to join. A private Ethereum testnet is only private because you've not told everyone you're running it. (There are probably a few further complexities here, but you get the idea.)

> What should I do, where to look at to start this process ? (After forking ethereum codebase)

- Clone the code from GitHub;
- Change the stuff you *want* to change (e.g. renaming certain parts, block difficulty calculations<sup>1</sup>, etc., etc., etc.);
- Change the stuff you *need* to change (e.g. hard-coded bootnodes);
- Distribute your version to the world.

<sup>1</sup>Changes such as these are questions in their own right, many of which have been asked before. It'll depend on what your aims are.