# Getting error while trying to generate genesis block?

Tags: go-ethereum, genesis

I am trying to generate the genesis block but getting an error:
[image]

Please guide me for this issue.

Comment: Your Image is not uploaded in the question! try again.

Comment: No idea why your python code is failing, anyway, you can use puppeth for creating the genesis file (https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/ -> Geth & Tools)

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Actually I want to clone Ethereum to make my own local currency based on Ethereum with a different name. But when I try to generate the genesis block then I am getting this error so whole process is stuck  on this point. Please guide me with all the steps for doing this. Right now I am following this process -> https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2014/how-to-fork-my-own-version-of-eth